# Seaside + jQuery variable check for onBlur

Tags: jquery, smalltalk, seaside

How do I code a variable check into a Seaside jQuery onSuccess: script?

I have an application with input fields that trigger a value change followed by a re-rendering of the view. It works nicely to provide lively feedback of domain data based on displayed values.

The view shows 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons if there are changes pending. If the user clicks on either button right after an input field, the onBlur: script of the input fields prevents the button action from taking place. The recommended solution ([button click event lost due to the alert box in text box onblur event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245350/button-click-event-lost-due-to-the-alert-box-in-text-box-onblur-event)) is to use the button's 'onmousedown' event to set a global variable that the onBlur script checks.

With my test code I can see the global 'saveCancelButtonClicked' being set, but I don't know how to check the value in order to prevent the rendering step.

```
html button 
  onMouseDown: 'saveCancelButtonClicked = 1;'; 
  ...

html textInput
 onBlur: ((
  html jQuery ajax 
      callback: [:stringValue | self checkValue: stringValue] 
          value: html jQuery this value)
      onSuccess: (
        (html jQuery id: 'selectedComponent') load html: [:renderer | 
          renderer script: 'console.log(saveCancelButtonClicked); '.
          self renderSelectedComponentOn: renderer]) )]
```

I can see the console.log showing '1' if the save button is pressed. 
So how do I check the value and skip the 'self renderSelectedComponentOn:' step?

It's easy enough to do in javascript (trivial if statement), but I have not found an example in Seaside.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim Tuchel answered this question on the Seaside mailing list:

```
onSuccess: (
    (JSStream on: 'saveCancelButtonClicked == 0') then: (
        (html jQuery id: 'portalSelectedComponent') load html: [:renderer |
```

...the method that renders the save and cancel buttons contains...

```
 html script: 'saveCancelButtonClicked = 0;' .
```

...both the save and cancel buttons implement...

```
 onMouseDown: 'saveCancelButtonClicked = 1;';
```

...works just as I wanted: pressing either the 'Save' or 'Cancel' button after updating an input field triggers the callback on the first click. 
And losing focus triggers the input field onBlur action normally.